# Java safe String.format and escaping %

Tags: java

I'm using `String.format` method of Java API to log something. My method is like:

```
public static void log(String message, Object... params){
    System.out.println(String.format(message, params));
}
```

However the problem is, if the user sends a message that has **`%`** character somewhere in it, it throws exception. Here's a scenario:

```
log("SELECT * FROM my WHERE name like '%six%'");
```

and Java looks for something to replace `%s` (that's ok) and `%'` (oops). I want to fix that. Because there there are no `params` and `%s` will be lost and `%'` causes exception.

One solution can be `message.replace("%", "%%")` but I'm not sure it is an elegant solution or not.

Comment: I don't see why `%s` would be OK if `%` isn't. If they give you broken input they can't expect working output. Just throw an exception.

Comment: @Christoffer I don't see the message string containing an SQL `like` clause as a broken input.

Comment: If the string contains both `%s` and `%`, and one is considered OK and the other is not, then the input is broken. If the input is a format string for `String.format()` and you don't want the `%s` in the `like` claused to be replaced by a parameter value, anything but `%%s` and `%%` in the input is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`log` has no idea whether a given `%` is meant as a format specifier or as a percent sign. Consider the following example:

```
log("%s%s", "test");
```

Is that `"test%s"`, `"%stest"`, or an error?

Therefore, the problem will have to be addressed at the call site:

```
log(escape("SELECT * FROM my WHERE name like '%six%'"));
```

where `escape()` is a function you'll need to write that'll replace all `%` with `%%`.

Alternatively, the following can be used at the call site:

```
log("%s", "SELECT * FROM my WHERE name like '%six%'");
```

Comment: Or perhaps, call the `escape()` method from within the `log()` method, making the operation seamless.

Comment: I used the last case and now my SQLs are logged like `log("%s", query);`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for the most likely misuse (using `%s` or `%` somewhere in the `String` but providing no parameters) would be to provide a no-params overload to your method *in addition* to your original method:

```
public static void log(String message) {
  System.out.println(message);
}
```

Alternatively you can dynamically try to detect the no-params case, but that's a bit more work:

```
public static void log(String message, Object... params) {
  final String output;
  if (params == null || params.length = 0) {
    output = message;
  } else {
    output = String.format(message, params);
  }
  System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Won't work if the client exploits the formatting-capabilities and does something like `%n`.

Comment: The two methods above are ambiguous since the first (with the var args) will take a 0-length list of params just as well.

Comment: @aioobe: true, it would need to be documented, but I see no real reason to use `%n` instead of `\n` here.

Comment: @John B: the compiler knows to use the no-params version if possible, it will not complain.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks. In your opinion would it be better to have a pair of overloads as I describe in my answer to reduce user ambiguity of which method is called (even if the compiler figures it out)?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the string directly into the println if the length of params is 0.
Another options would be to have two overloads.

```
public static void log(String message);
public static void log(String format, String param, String...params);
```

Comment: I don't think the fixed `param` is necessary. Also: format parameters can be `Object`, so `log` should accept `Object` as well.

Comment: But do you feel it provides more readability since there is no potential confusion over which overload is called in the no-arg case?

Comment: that's true, it's more obvious, but it has drawbacks. For example if for some reason I already *have* the array (possibly because the calling method is itself a variable arity method): then you'll have to copy the array to call the `log` method.